# Recording audio with NAudio cuts me off

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio, google-speech-to-text-api

I am recording an audio to send it to send it to Google speech to text but when I make the audio with naudio it records me only 5 seconds and from there it stops recording. I copy the code in C #, this is my first time using this API, but I don't know why it cuts me, if it should stop recording when I press the save button, the application is a simple form with 2 buttons, one for recording and the other for stop.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private BufferedWaveProvider bwp;
        WaveIn waveIn;
        WaveOut waveOut;
        WaveFileWriter writer;
        WaveFileReader reader;
        string output = "audio.raw";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            waveOut = new WaveOut();
            waveIn = new WaveIn();

            waveIn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveIn_DataAvailable);
            waveIn.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, 1);
            bwp = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveIn.WaveFormat);
            bwp.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;

            btnRecordVoice.Enabled = true;
            btnSave.Enabled = false;
            //btnSpeechInfo.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnRecordVoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No se encuentra un microfono!");
                return;
            }

            waveIn.StartRecording();

            btnRecordVoice.Enabled = false;
            btnSave.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            waveIn.StopRecording();

            if (File.Exists("audio.raw"))
                File.Delete("audio.raw");

            writer = new WaveFileWriter(output, waveIn.WaveFormat);

            btnRecordVoice.Enabled = false;
            btnSave.Enabled = false;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bwp.BufferLength];
            int offset = 0;
            int count = bwp.BufferLength;

            var read = bwp.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            if (count > 0)
            {
                writer.Write(buffer, offset, read);
            }

            waveIn.Dispose();
            waveIn = null;
            writer.Close();
            writer = null;

            reader = new WaveFileReader("audio.raw"); // (new MemoryStream(bytes));
            waveOut.Init(reader);
            waveOut.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveOut_PlaybackStopped);
            waveOut.Play();
        }

        void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            bwp.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

        }

        private void waveOut_PlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            waveOut.Stop();
            reader.Close();
            reader = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is English language only. I’ve edited your question using Google Translate, please check it to make sure it’s ok

Comment: The code in `btnSave_Click()` to copy from the `BufferedWaveProvider` to a `WaveFileWriter` is...odd.  You store the result of `bwp.Read()` in `read`, but then check `count`, which was a parameter (upper-bound) of `bwp.Read()`.  Also, typically those `Read(byte[], int, int)` methods aren't guaranteed to read all of the requested data, so you need a loop, not an `if`.  Try something like `int read; while ((read = bwp.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) { writer.Write(buffer, 0, read); }`.

Answer (score 1):

You get a 5-second audio clip not only because you do a one-time `BufferLength` read from the `BufferedWaveProvider`...

```cs
int count = bwp.BufferLength;

var read = bwp.Read(buffer, offset, count);
```

...and 5 seconds is the [default value of that property](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/6cfd03dc59c5c4e1373893a8cb48bdf08afea9ab/NAudio/Wave/WaveProviders/BufferedWaveProvider.cs#L24), but because `BufferedWaveProvider` [uses a circular buffer](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/6cfd03dc59c5c4e1373893a8cb48bdf08afea9ab/NAudio/Wave/WaveProviders/BufferedWaveProvider.cs#L98), so `BufferLength` is all the data it has available.

What worked for me was to skip the `BufferedWaveProvider` and write new data to the `WaveFileWriter` as soon as it becomes available...

```cs
void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    writer.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}
```

To support that change, the button event handlers get changed to the following...

```cs
private void btnRecordVoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No se encuentra un microfono!");
        return;
    }

    writer = new WaveFileWriter(output, waveIn.WaveFormat);
    waveIn.StartRecording();

    btnRecordVoice.Enabled = false;
    btnSave.Enabled = true;
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    waveIn.StopRecording();
    writer.Close();
    writer = null;

    btnRecordVoice.Enabled = false;
    btnSave.Enabled = false;

    reader = new WaveFileReader("audio.raw"); // (new MemoryStream(bytes));
    waveOut.Init(reader);
    waveOut.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveOut_PlaybackStopped);
    waveOut.Play();
}
```

This appears to be the same approach used in [Recording a WAV file in a WinForms app with WaveIn](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RecordWavFileWinFormsWaveIn.md).